# Мнимые числа в python

Tags: python

Добрый день, есть список, примерно такой:

```
     [(0.55773011861+0.966016929j), (1.63099590361+2.82465006773j),      (2.4131580717499039+4.17971238644j)]
```

нужно у комплексных чисел взять мнимые или реальные части, т.е получить:

```
     [0.5577301186126, 1.630812759959036, 2.413158071749903]
```

И наоборот, что-то пока не пойму как это сделать, а в поисковике ничего толкового не нашёл.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
m = [(0.55773011861+0.966016929j), (1.63099590361+2.82465006773j),      (2.4131580717499039+4.17971238644j)]

[n.real for n in m]
[0.55773011861, 1.63099590361, 2.413158071749904]

[n.imag for n in m]
[0.966016929, 2.82465006773, 4.17971238644]
```

Думаю вы об этом

Comment: Да, вы правы, большое спасибо.

Comment: Или по-старому:

    map (lambda x: x.real, m)
    map (lambda x: x.imag, m)